# Projection of algebraic set on hyperplane is closed

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is an algebraic set of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

We defined the projection $\pi$ as follows: Let $P$ be a point in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $H$ a hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $P \notin \mathbb{P}^n$. We project every point $Q \neq P$ $\in \mathbb{P}^n$, the line $\overline{PQ}$ will cut $H$ at a point $\pi(Q)$.

We would like to prove that $\pi(X)$ with $X$ an algebraic set is closed, but we're stuck with our reasoning.

This is what we already thought about: For a random point $Q \in X$ there is a line $PQ$ between $Q$ and $P$. We can write that $PQ =Z(f_1,...,f_{n-1})$ with $f_1,...,f_{n-1}$ irreducible polynomials. We also know that we can write $H = Z(g)$ with $g$ an irreducible polynomial. Here we are stuck. We have a feeling that we can do something with resultants but we don't know what or how.

Hopefully someone can help us.

Answer (score 1):

This should follow from the exposition in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432534/dimension-of-projection-of-projective-variety-on-hyperplane/3442018#3442018) I wrote the other day. Briefly, define $J(X,P)$, the join variety of $X$ and $P$, to be all the points which are on a line through $P$ and a point of $X$ which isn't $P$. This is a closed subset. Then the projection of $X$ onto $H$ from $P$ is exactly $J(X,P)\cap H$, which is closed as the intersection of two closed subsets.