# The dimension of non-generic projections of an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ be an (irreducible) affine variety of dimension $m$ and degree $d$. As I understand, for a generic direction $0\neq v\in\mathbb{C}^n$, the orthogonal projection $\pi:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n/\langle v\rangle$ has the nice property that $\pi(V)$ is closed and has the same dimension as $V$. I want to know the dimension of the variety $W\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ defined as the set of all directions for which the projection does not have this nice property (for $V$). I am also curious about the defining equations of the variety. It looks like these bad directions are the ones such that the line passes through a point in the projective closure of $V$ (and not through any other point of $V$), but I cannot see how I can use it to calculate the dimension of the equations.

If I am not mistaken, in the case that $V$ is a projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$, any point $p\not\in V$ has the nice property (for the projection away from $p$) and some other points in $V$. In particular, the bad points form a variety of dimension at most $\dim V$ and usually even smaller (if $V$ is not a linear subspace, if I understand correctly). The details are in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432534/dimension-of-projection-of-projective-variety-on-hyperplane).

I suspect that the dimension will be the same in the affine case. But in the projective case I only care about $\dim V=\dim\pi(V)$ property whereas in the affine case I also care about $\pi(V)$ being closed.