# Non existence of homogeneous polynomials defining a morphism between projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-varieties, morphism

Given the quadric $Q=V(XT-YZ)\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ and the lines $L_{X,Y}=V(X,Y)\subset Q$ and $L_{Z,T}=V(Z,T)\subset Q$, we have the morphism $\Phi: Q\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^{1}$ given by:

$\Phi(X,Y,Z,T)=\begin{cases}
(Z,T),\;\text{ in } Q\setminus L_{Z,T}\\
(X,Y),\;\text{ in } Q\setminus L_{X,Y}\\
\end{cases}$,

which is clearly well defined since both images coincide in $(Q\setminus L_{Z,T})\cap (Q\setminus L_{X,Y})$.

**My question is the following:**

I want to prove that the morphism $\Phi$ cannot be written as $\Phi(X,Y,Z,T)=(P_{1}(X,Y,Z,T),\;P_{2}(X,Y,Z,T))$ for all $(X,Y,Z,T)\in\mathbb{P}^3$, where $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree.

**My attempt has been the following:**

My idea was to prove that such polynomials cannot exists because they would share some common zeros and then the point $[0:0:0:0]$ will be in the image of the morphism, which cannot be possible.

To do so, I use the relation given by the quadric $Q$, i.e. $XT-YZ$, to express $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ as polynomials with the form $P_{1}(X,Y,Z,T)=F_{1}(X,Y,T)+G_{1}(X,Z,T)$ and $P_{2}(X,Y,Z,T)=F_{2}(X,Y,T)+G_{2}(X,Z,T)$, where $F$ and $G$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree as $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$.

Then, I have tried to see how the polynomials $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ behave when applied on points from $L_{X,Y}$ and $L_{Z,T}$ (especially in the points $[1:0:0:0],\;[0:1:0:0],\;[0:0:1:0],\;[0:0:0:1]$) and imposing the conditions given by the morphism $\Phi$.

However, I have not been capable to prove that $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ share any common zero in $Q$. I would be very grateful if someone could help me to figure out how to show that both polinomyals $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ vanish at some common point in $Q$.

Thanks!

Comment: If you know how the dimension of intersections works in projective space (for instance, as outlined in [the projective dimension theorem in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432534/dimension-of-projection-of-projective-variety-on-hyperplane/3442018#3442018)) you'll be good to go - the dimension of the intersection of your variety and the zero sets of those two polynomials will be of nonnegative dimension in $\Bbb P^3$ and therefore nonempty.